# Catching informations about running processes in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

My task is to make a program, which counts a time of running processes in windows. Can you suggest me how or from where can I catch that informations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For list of currently running processes under Windows use EnumProcesses win32 API

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

example how to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

From your question I'm not sure if you need process timing information (CPU time,etc.) or to count instances of given process in memory. Could you please explain this more clearly ?

You can use GetProcessTimes function to get process timing information.